# Video Upload with Graph API including a URL in the video's message parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-php-sdk

I'm in progress to create a new website that about videos..
People there accept my FB app then they will be able to share videos in their timelines.

It's not a share, the process of that share will work with Video Upload by Graph API.

There's a plenty of parameters when uploading videos with Graph API.
One of those is "message", that is point to the description that will be shown above the video.

My question is: If I include the URL of the original video(URL of the video on my website) in the bottom of that video's description, may this will ban my Facebook application?

I had something like that with "Image Upload with Graph API".. But nowadays I see some guys who do what I'm asking about without any issues!

Any suggestions from Facebook developers?

Comment: Short answer yes - if you're doing it yourself on your own page it's probably OK, but you can't prefill any of those fields (video title, message, photo caption) with content other than what users themselves typed

Comment: @Igy ohh, bad news.. What about some apps that do that? People even couldn't write descriptions themselves..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What luck :(

Sadly, no way to auto-fill the message with an URL, hashtags or something like that.

Users have to do that manually.

This page is clarify that:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill